# Bootstrap place button in one line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to fix a button `Close` because when width of screen decreasing it slip under the `save` button. How to prevent this by bootstrap or css?

Link on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/a191919/pen/yOrjNj) because it does not happens in stack snippet.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
             <input type="submit" value="Close" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the div that surrounds the buttons `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 0):

> Link on Codepen because it does not happens in stack snippet.

This is possibly likely because your Codepen is using `col-xs-2` and your code here is using `col-md-2`.

If you're actually struggling with `col-xs`, then:

Another option is to simply use a different `col-*` class to increase the width instead of `xs`:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    <input type="submit" value="Close" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
```